# Why can't I add group by clause into this query?

Tags: sql, group-by

I was filling this exercise from Sqlzoo.

Which countries have a GDP greater than every country in Europe? [Give the name only.] (Some countries may have NULL gdp values)
the answer is

select name, continent
from world 
where gdp >=all(select gdp 
            from world 
             where gdp>0 and continent='Europe')  and continent!='Europe'

and results are

name
China
Japan
United States

but when I try to group and count them according to their continents it does not allow me to do it.

*select **count(name), continent**
from world 
where gdp >=all(select gdp 
            from world 
             where gdp>0 and continent='Europe')  and continent!='Europe' and **group by continent***

it gives me a syntax error. it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near **'group by continent'** at line 1"

Why does not it allow me do that?

6th exercise in that address https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: You don't say `and group by continent`, rather just use `group by continent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove last `and`. `group by` is not condition

try it

```
select count(name), continent 
from world 
where gdp >=all(select gdp 
                 from world 
                 where gdp>0 
                 and continent='Europe') 
and continent!='Europe' 
group by continent
```